# Spurious blank row with longtable and expl3 map function

Tags: longtable, expl3

I've got some data in an expl3 sequence, which I'm using in a longtable. All works fine, but I'm getting an additional blank row after the inline map body. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{longtable}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printData}{}
 {
   \begin{longtable}{l}
     \hline
     Minimal~Working~Example \\
     \hline
     \endhead
     End \\
     \hline
     \endfoot
     \clist_map_inline:nn
       {comma,separated,list,of,data,also,fails,with,seq}
       {
         ##1 \\
         \hline
       }
% Uncomment to fill the blank row
%       Mystery row here! \\ \hline
   \end{longtable}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\printData
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Blank row]

The intention is for the final loop of the inline map to close with an `\hline`, running straight into the footer. I'm on an older version of texlive and pdflatex (from Ubuntu 18.04), but this error is also present on overleaf, which I'm assuming is up to date, so I presume the error is mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\clist_map_function:nN` otherwise a cell would be started; to the contrary, `\clist_map_function:nN` delivers its complete result before anything that TeX takes as the start of a cell is considered.

Tables are well known to be a source of problems of this kind.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{longtable}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printData}{}
 {
  \begin{longtable}{l}
  \hline
  Minimal~Working~Example \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  End \\
  \hline
  \endfoot
  \clist_map_function:nN {comma,separated,list,of,data} \aejh_entry:n
  \end{longtable}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aejh_entry:n { #1 \\ \hline }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printData

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks.